# Create 'edit email address' functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails framework and want to create 'edit email address' functionality for user so that user can easily change its email address.but I have no idea how can I create that functionality. Please give some idea.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a 'crud' controller for the model that has email as its field. u can edit the email in 'edit' form. see  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have user in my application and has there own account and I want to create functionality so that he/she can change there account setting like change email address(like in Gmail account setting ,we can change our email address or reset password). Here I only want to reset my email

Comment: if ur model is User with fields [email, name] then create UsersController with edit n update methods.

Comment: Thanks prasad for your's kind help